# I want to convert bytes literal that's hardcoded in string

Tags: python

I have a string like this.

```
X = "b'\\xec\\x9c\\xa4\\xec\\xa7\\x84'"
```

X is basically http response that should've been decoded first before sending the response. As a result, it became like that.

And what I want to do is making X to Y... and Y is..

```
Y = b'\xec\x9c\xa4\xec\xa7\x84'
```

So that I can decode Y in UTF-8.

Please lead me the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also can use `eval`.

```
X = "b'\\xec\\x9c\\xa4\\xec\\xa7\\x84'"
eval(X).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: `eval` is extremely poor practice as the response could contain malicious executable data, open up the OP to all sorts of security risks. -1

Comment: Nearly 10 years old and still valid: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`.

```
>>> import ast
>>>
>>> X = "b'\\xec\\x9c\\xa4\\xec\\xa7\\x84'"
>>> ast.literal_eval(X).decode('utf-8')
'윤진'
```